# How to set up AH Bot Azerothcore

Tags: azerothcore

Asking the question and then I'm going to answer it. I'm doing this because I had a lot of trouble setting up and realized there really isn't a great guide detailing how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: clone the git repo to a folder (ex. C:\Users\Cam\Desktop\mod-ah-bot) on your local server. Here's the link: https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-ah-bot.git (You must clone the repo, simply downloading it did not work for me)

Step 2: Move the folder you just cloned that repo to into your Azerothcore/Modules folder. The whole folder, throw it in there.

Step 3: Grab the "mod_ahbot.conf.dist" file from the 'conf' folder (mod-ah-bot/conf) and throw it in the same directory as your worldserver.exe.

Step 4: You'll want to modify that file to your preferences. Just change the name to "mod_ahbot.conf", edit the file, save the file, then change the name back to "mod_ahbot.conf.dist"

Step 5: Open cmake (you would've used this before to build your server if you followed the install directions on AzerothCore site, here's the link: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/windows-core-installation , specifically the cmake section.

Step 6: Ensure the source code directory (AzerothCore location) is filled in at the top. (ex. C:/users/$user/desktop/azerothcore)

Then fill in the binaries location under that (ex. C:/users/$user/desktop/build)

Step 7: Click configure on the bottom left, then click generate, then click open project.

Step 8: Right click "Solution 'AzerothCore' (26 of 26 projects" located on the left side of VS code and click 'Rebuild Solution'

Step 9: Wait for binaries to compile or whatever magic is happening there.

Step 10: Lets go back to that mod-ah-bot folder we cloned and open the sql folder. Go a few folders deep and you're going to find a .sql file. Run that against your acore_world database.

Step 11: Assuming there were no red flags! Launch your Authserver.exe, then launch your wowserver.exe and at the end of the wowserver.exe cmd window it should say this: "AuctionHouseBot and AuctionHouseBuyer have been loaded." If it does celebrate!! And get to tweaking the mod_auctionhousebot table that sql query we ran created to your liking.

If it didn't, well... yeah..